# Updating properties in Lists of Lists

Tags: c#, list

The question is: How can I update the field ItemCount inside allItems without loop (using Linq, for example)? For example, if Index = 0, I want to set ItemCount to ItemCount-5.

You can see the code below.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
    private int index;
    private string item_name;
    private double item_count;
    private string type_name;

    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        set { index = value; }
    }
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return item_name; }
        set { item_name = value; }
    }
    public double ItemCount
    {
        get { return item_count; }
        set { item_count = value; }
    }
    public string TypeName
    {
        get { return type_name; }
        set { type_name = value; }
    }

}

public class CombMin
{
    private double min_count;
    private List<Item> combination;

    public double MinCount
    {
        get { return min_count; }
        set { min_count = value; }
    }
    public List<Item> Combination
    {
        get { return combination; }
        set { combination = value; }
    }
}
```

Then I created List allItems:

```
        var item1 = new Item { Index=0,ItemName="x1",ItemCount=104,TypeName="Type1" };
        var item2 = new Item { Index = 1, ItemName = "x2", ItemCount = 104, TypeName = "Type1" };
        var item3 = new Item { Index = 2, ItemName = "x3", ItemCount = 1495, TypeName = "Type1" };
        var item4 = new Item { Index = 0, ItemName = "x1", ItemCount = 104, TypeName = "Type1" };
        var item5 = new Item { Index = 1, ItemName = "x2", ItemCount = 104, TypeName = "Type1" };
        var item6 = new Item { Index = 2, ItemName = "x3", ItemCount = 1495, TypeName = "Type1" };

        var items1 = new List<Item>();
        var items2 = new List<Item>();
        items1.Add(item1);
        items1.Add(item2);
        items1.Add(item3);

        items2.Add(item4);
        items2.Add(item5);
        items2.Add(item6);

        var allItems = new List<CombMin>();
        allItems.Add(new CombMin { Combination = items1, MinCount = 104 });
        allItems.Add(new CombMin { Combination = items2, MinCount = 104 });
```

The question is: How can I update the field ItemCount inside allItems without loop (using Linq)? For example, if Index = 0, I want to set ItemCount to ItemCount-5.

Comment: _"without loop (using Linq)"_ So you think LINQ doesn't use loops?

Comment: If you're not implementing custom get and setters on properties, why don't you use {get; set;} after the properties ? That would make your code soo much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Basic Solution:

```
allItems.ForEach(x => x.Combination.FirstOrDefault(ele => ele.Index == 0).ItemCount -= 5);
```

> As mentioned in comment if there is only 1 element with index 1 then you can do is :

```
   allItems.ForEach(x => x.Combination.First(ele => ele.Index == 0).ItemCount -= 5);
```

> If you are not sure that the given index exists in the collection you can do is

```
CombMin element = new CombMin();
int index = 25;//does not exists in the collection
element = allItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Combination.Any(ele => ele.Index == index));
if (element != null)
    element.Combination.FirstOrDefault(ele => ele.Index == index).ItemCount -= 5;
```

Comment: If there is no item with `Index==0` this will throw an exception. [Rahuls answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909268/284240) handles that case

Comment: @TimSchmelter is right. If no item has `Index==0` the `FirstOrDefault` will retun `null` which will give you a `NullReferenceException` when trying to set the `ItemCount`

Comment: ForEach is a Loop.. haha. But... I Believe the author just wanted to avoid doing the loop himself. Btw, its ItemCount = ItemCount-5;

Comment: If there is always one item with `Index==0` you could use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. If there is none, this will throw(as mentioned), if there are multiple then this would only update the first.

Comment: well index seems a unique variable I dont think there will be `dupes` also should I use `Any()`?

Comment: @Lucifer: sure, but nothing in this class avoids duplicate indexes or ensures one with index=0. You could use `Any` to check if there's one, but then you would execute the query twice which would be inefficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter agreed ,See I have posted a solution regarding this but I had to iterate twice through the collection which indeed makes it inefficient

Answer (score 2):

Linq is used for querying not for updating records. So first get records using linq and then iterate through the collection and update.

In your case it should be:

```
foreach (var x in allItems)
{
    foreach (var y in x.Combination)
    {
        if (y.Index == 0)
        {
            y.ItemCount = 105;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909268/284240) is right, LINQ should be used to query  something not to modify it. But he could have used LINQ to determine what has to be updated. So this is my favorite here:

```
IEnumerable<Item> itemsToUpdateWithIndex0 = allItems
    .SelectMany(c => c.Combination)
    .Where(item => item.Index == 0);

foreach (Item item in itemsToUpdateWithIndex0)
    item.ItemCount -= 5;
```